# Using hide my ass from a server

Tags: php, proxy

So i'm trying to use Hide my ass http://www.hidemyass.com/ to get data from a site. I want to be able to send a link into search and then get hide my ass URL to that page. So for example i insert from a server a link to a webpage let say google: http://google.com and in return i get something like that

http://7.hidemyass.com/ip-1/encoded/Oi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20v

Is it possible and if it's how is it possible. Thank u all!

ps. If something isn't clear i can explain.

p.s.s I noticed that same url is always encoded into same url string, so it would be ok i can just encode URL the same way they do.

Comment: It's actually all clear: you want to cheat against 2 sites owners. How about starting creating something new, not stealing others' property?

Comment: Actualy not. I'm trying to parse string from a site and use some data from it. Nothing illegal or anything. But because that site know i'm not from USA i can't get same data as USA people, so I'm trying to trick it.

Comment: Use something like **cURL**, if you're stuck come back again ...

Comment: @gabrjan: "Nothing illegal", "But because that site know i'm not from USA i can't get same data as USA people". If that's what site owner want - you don't have choice, otherwise it's not a right thing.

Comment: I don't know how i'm lying? So to be clear I'm trying to read top games from play.google but i always get some games that are specifical jsut for my country. So i want best in USA.

Comment: I don't have an idea where to start and how to start.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know PHP but here are some guidelines to help you figure it out.
See the source of any page using HideMyAss. Here's the form for the URL bar

```
<form action="/includes/process.php?action=update&amp;idx=1" method="post"id="hmaform">
  <input type="hidden" name="obfuscation" value="1">
  <input id="hmainput" type="text" name="u" value="your url here">
  <input id="hmasubmit" type="image" src="/images/proxified/submit-button.png" value="">
</form>
```

As you can see you only need to https POST to given URL. And it will probably respond with a http redirect you can parse to extract the URL.